# Speed matrix multiplications

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

I am trying to run this function

```
Pfun[M_, G_] := 
  Module[{resfn, P, resmatrix}, 

   P[u_, v_] := Sum[M[[i,u]]*M[[j,v]]*A[[i,j]], {i, n}, {j, n}]/
      (Total[M[[All,u]]]*Total[M[[All,v]]]); 

   resfn[i_, u_] := 
    Product[
     (If[P[u, v] < 10^(-3), 
        (10^(-3))^Sum[M[[j,v]]*A[[i,j]], {j, Complement[Range[n], {i}]}], 
        P[u, v]^Sum[M[[j,v]]*A[[i,j]], {j, Complement[Range[n], {i}]}]]) 
      (If[1 - P[u, v] < 10^(-3), 
        (10^(-3))^Sum[M[[j,v]]*(1 - A[[i,j]]), 
          {j, Complement[Range[n], {i}]}], (1 - P[u, v])^
         Sum[M[[j,v]]*(1 - A[[i,j]]), {j, Complement[Range[n], {i}]}]]), 
      {v, k}]; 

   resmatrix = Table[resfn[i, u], {i, n}, {u, k}]];
```

but it takes so much time.  How can I increase the speed of this function?

Here `M` and `A` are 0-1 matrices, and `G` is real matrix.  I am trying for `n = 1162` and `k = 3`.

Comment: You might want to try expressing your functions in terms of actual dot products, for starters...

Comment: Can you be more specific? thanks

Comment: Something for you to start with: `P[u_, v_] := M[[All, u]].A.M[[All, v]]/(Total[M[[All, u]]] Total[M[[All, v]]])`. Once more: look into using dot products.

Comment: thanks I will try it and get back here afterwards

Comment: Avoid using upper-case letters (`A`, `P`, `M`, `G`, etc.) or words that begin with upper-case letters (`Pfun`, etc.) as these may conflict with internal names in *Mathematica*.